# Synthesis operator in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider a Banach space $X$, the synthesis operator $U$ is defined as $U_{C}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} x_{n}$ where $\left(c_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^{p}$. My question is: Is this operator a bounded map of $ \ell^{p} \text { into } X$ for all $1 \leq p \leq \infty$?

My thought is the first step is to show that for a fixed $\left\{x_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text { in a Banach space } X$,  the series$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} x_{n}$  converges for each sequence $\left(c_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^{p}$. However I've no idea how to show that. Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot show this if you  don't have any information about $(x_n)$.

Comment: Does synthesis operator associate with $\{x_n\}$? What other information is needed other than $\left\{x_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text { in a Banach space } X$ and it's fixed?

Comment: @Maskoff what is $X$? What is the domain and what is the range of $U$? You specify that $(c_n)\in\ell^p$, but what is $(x_n)$ ?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn $X$ is a Banach space, range is defined as $U_{C}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} x_{n}$, $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $X$.

Comment: So what is the domain of the operator?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn From $\ell^{p} \text { into } X$

Comment: It depends on $x_n$, if $x_n=0$ for all $n$ then this is always defined. If $x_n$ is something of norm $2^n$ this is defined for very few elements of $\ell^p$.